# Finding the optimal location for router placement

Tags: python, algorithm, optimization, text-files

I am looking for an optimization algorithm that takes a text file encoded with 0s, 1s, and -1s:

- 1's denoting target cells that requires Wi-Fi coverage
- 0's denoting cells that are walls
- 1's denoting cells that are void (do not require Wi-Fi coverage)

Example of text file:
[image: Example of text file]

I have created a solution function along with other helper functions, but I can't seem to get the optimal positions of the routers to be placed to ensure proper coverage. There is another file that does the printing, I am struggling with finding the optimal location. I basically need to change the `get_random_position` function to get the optimal one, but I am unsure how to do that. The area covered by the various routers are:

This is the kind of output I am getting:
[image: This is the kind of output I am getting]

**Each router covers a square area of at most (2S+1)^2**

- Type 1: S=5; Cost=180
- Type 2: S=9; Cost=360
- Type 3: S=15; Cost=480

My code is as follows:

```
import numpy as np
import time

from random import randint

def is_taken(taken, i, j):
    for coords in taken:
        if coords[0] == i and coords[1] == j:
            return True
return False

def get_random_position(floor, taken , nrows, ncols):
  i = randint(0, nrows-1)
  j = randint(0, ncols-1)

  while floor[i][j] == 0 or floor[i][j] == -1 or is_taken(taken, i, j):
      i = randint(0, nrows-1)
      j = randint(0, ncols-1)

  return (i, j)

def solution(floor):
  start_time = time.time()
  router_types = [1,2,3]

  nrows, ncols = floor.shape
  ratio = 0.1
  router_scale = int(nrows*ncols*0.0001)
  if router_scale == 0:
     router_scale = 1
row_ratio = int(nrows*ratio)
col_ratio = int(ncols*ratio)

print('Row  : ',nrows, ', Col: ', ncols, ', Router scale :', router_scale)

global_best = [0, ([],[],[])]
taken = []
while True:
    found_better = False
    best = [global_best[0], (list(global_best[1][0]), list(global_best[1][1]), list(global_best[1][2]))]  
    for times in range(0, row_ratio+col_ratio):
        if time.time() - start_time > 27.0:
            print('Time ran out! Using what I got : ', time.time() - start_time)
            return global_best[1]

        fit = []
        for rtype in router_types:
            interim = (list(global_best[1][0]), list(global_best[1][1]), list(global_best[1][2]))

            for i in range(0, router_scale):
                pos = get_random_position(floor, taken, nrows, ncols)
                interim[0].append(pos[0])
                interim[1].append(pos[1])

                interim[2].append(rtype)

            fit.append((fitness(floor, interim), interim))

        highest_fitness = fit[0]
        for index in range(1, len(fit)):
            if fit[index][0] > highest_fitness[0]:
                highest_fitness = fit[index]

        if highest_fitness[0] > best[0]:
            best[0] = highest_fitness[0]
            best[1] = (highest_fitness[1][0],highest_fitness[1][1], highest_fitness[1][2])
            found_better = True
            global_best = best
            taken.append((best[1][0][-1],best[1][1][-1]))
            break


    if found_better == False:
        break

print('Best:')        
print(global_best)                

end_time = time.time()
run_time = end_time - start_time
print("Run Time:", run_time)


return global_best[1]

def available_cells(floor):
    available = 0
    for i in range(0, len(floor)):
        for j in range(0, len(floor[i])):
            if floor[i][j] != 0:
                available += 1
   return available            



def fitness(building, args):
    render = np.array(building, dtype=int, copy=True)
    cov_factor = 220
    cost_factor = 22
    router_types = {  # type: [coverage, cost]
        1: {'size' : 5, 'cost' : 180},
        2: {'size' : 9, 'cost' : 360},
        3: {'size' : 15, 'cost' : 480},
    }
    routers_used = args[-1]

for r, c, t in zip(*args):
    size = router_types[t]['size']
    nrows, ncols = render.shape
    rows = range(max(0, r-size), min(nrows, r+size+1))
    cols = range(max(0, c-size), min(ncols, c+size+1))

    walls = []
    for ri in rows:
        for ci in cols:
            if building[ri, ci] == 0:
                walls.append((ri, ci))

    def blocked(ri, ci):
        for w in walls:
            if min(r, ri) <= w[0] and max(r, ri) >= w[0]:
                if min(c, ci) <= w[1] and max(c, ci) >= w[1]:
                    return True
        return False

    for ri in rows:
        for ci in cols:
            if blocked(ri, ci):
                continue
            if render[ri, ci] == 2:
                render[ri, ci] = 4
            if render[ri, ci] == 1:
                render[ri, ci] = 2

    render[r, c] = 5

return (
        cov_factor * np.sum(render > 1) - 
        cost_factor * np.sum([router_types[x]['cost'] for x in routers_used])
    )
```

Comment: How is "proper coverage" defined in the scope of this problem?

Comment: @Ajax1234 Proper coverage is defined by having all the valid locations coverage - in the image, the green symbolises the area that has internet access based on the placement of the router( maroon) , so if its close to a wall it reduces coverage, but further away gives more coverage

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a suggestion on how to solve the problem; however I don't affirm this is the best approach, and it's certainly not the only one.

## Main idea

Your problem can be modelised as a [weighted minimum set cover problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_cover_problem).

Good news, this is a well known optimization problem:

- It is easy to find algorithm descriptions for approximate solutions
- A quick search on the web shows many implementations of approximation algorithms in Python.

Bad news, this is a [NP-hard optimization problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimization_problem#NP_optimization_problem):

- If you need an exact solution: algorithms will work only for "small" sized problems in a reasonable amount of time(in your case: size of the problem <=> number of "1" cells).
- Approximate (a.k.a greedy) algorithms are trade-off between computation requirements, and a risk do deliver far from optimal solutions in certain cases.

Note that the following part does **not** prove that your problem is NP-hard. The general minimum set cover problem is NP-hard. In your case the subsets have several properties that might help to design a better algorithm. I have no idea how though.

## Translating into a cover set problem

Let's define some sets:

- U: the set of "1" cells (requiring Wifi).
- P(U): the [power set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_set) of U (the set of subsets of U).
- P: the set of cells on which you can place a router (not sure if P=U in your original post).
- T: the set of router type (3 values in your case).
- R+: positive Real number (used to describe prices).

Let's define a function (pseudo Python):

```
# Domain of definition : T,P --> R+,P(U)
# This function takes a router type and a position, and returns
# a tuple containing:
# - the price of a router of the given type.
# - the subset of U containing all the position covered by a router
#   of the given type placed at the given position.
def weighted_subset(routerType, position):
    pass # TODO: implementation
```

Now, we define a last set, as the image of the function we've just described: `S=weighted_subset(T,P)`. Each element of this set is a subset of U, weighted by a price in R+.

With all this formalism, finding the router types & positions that:

1. gives coverage to all the desirable locations
2. minimize the cost

Is equivalent to finding a sub-collection of S:

1. whose union of their P(U) is equal to U
2. which minimise the sum of the associated weights

Which is the weighted minimal set cover problem.